# force redirect users to respective sub-site (wordpress multi-site)

Tags: php, wordpress

So does anyone know how to implement code that checks if users are a member of the site and if not, redirect them to their respective sub-site? Essentially, I am trying to restrict logged in users to the sub-site they are registered in, so when they try to access the main site or a different sub-site, they get redirected to their sub-site homepage.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of Wordpress plugins that allow you to do this sort of thing.

I would recommend ['Multisite User Management'](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-user-management/). You will then simply need to apply a specific user role to each site, and edit the user role verification code to redirect users as appropriate.

If this doesn't help, I would advise searching for ['User Roles'](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=user%20role) and ['Multisite User Management'](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=multisite%20user%20management) in the Wordpress plugin search. There is a wealth to choose from and at least one of them should do most of what you need.